# Graph API bug changing recurrence from "noEnd" to "numbered"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have an event in Outlook with an attendee that uses Google calendar. When I change the event recurrence range type using the graph API from "noEnd" to "numbered", the google attendee's event does not get updated.

Here is the code I am using to set the recurrence as "noEnd":

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SetDailyRecurrenceForever(string ExternalID, string CalendarRefreshToken)
    {
        var tmpEvent = new Microsoft.Graph.Event
        {
            Recurrence = new PatternedRecurrence
            {
                Pattern = new RecurrencePattern
                {
                    Type = RecurrencePatternType.Daily,
                    Interval = 1,
                    FirstDayOfWeek = Microsoft.Graph.DayOfWeek.Sunday,
                    Index = WeekIndex.First
                },
                Range = new RecurrenceRange
                {
                    Type = RecurrenceRangeType.NoEnd,
                    StartDate = new Microsoft.Graph.Date(2020,10,6),
                    RecurrenceTimeZone = "Central Standard Time",
                    NumberOfOccurrences = 0
                }
            }
        };

        var graphClient = await MicrosoftAuthenticationProvider.GetGraphClient(CALENDAR_CLIENT_ID, CALENDAR_CLIENT_SECRET, CALENDAR_REDIRECT_URI, CALENDAR_ACCESS_SCOPES, CalendarRefreshToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

        
            await graphClient.Me.Events[ExternalID]
            .Request()
            .UpdateAsync(tmpEvent)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);           
    }
```

Here is the code I am using to set the recurrence as "numbered":

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SetDailyRecurrenceForFiveDays(string ExternalID, string CalendarRefreshToken)
    {
        var tmpEvent = new Microsoft.Graph.Event
        {
            Recurrence = new PatternedRecurrence
            {
                Pattern = new RecurrencePattern
                {
                    Type = RecurrencePatternType.Daily,
                    Interval = 1,
                    FirstDayOfWeek = Microsoft.Graph.DayOfWeek.Sunday,
                    Index = WeekIndex.First
                },
                Range = new RecurrenceRange
                {
                    Type = RecurrenceRangeType.Numbered,
                    StartDate = new Microsoft.Graph.Date(2020, 10, 6),
                    RecurrenceTimeZone = "Central Standard Time",
                    NumberOfOccurrences = 5
                }
            }
        };

        var graphClient = await MicrosoftAuthenticationProvider.GetGraphClient(CALENDAR_CLIENT_ID, CALENDAR_CLIENT_SECRET, CALENDAR_REDIRECT_URI, CALENDAR_ACCESS_SCOPES, CalendarRefreshToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);


        await graphClient.Me.Events[ExternalID]
        .Request()
        .UpdateAsync(tmpEvent)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

The bug is also repeatable by sending a PATCH using the graph explorer:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{ID}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/%7BID%7D)

Update the event as "noEnd":

```
{"recurrence":{"pattern":{"type":"daily","interval":1,"month":0,"dayOfMonth":0,"firstDayOfWeek":"sunday","index":"first"},"range":{"type":"noEnd","startDate":"2020-10-06","endDate":"0001-01-01","recurrenceTimeZone":"Central Standard Time","numberOfOccurrences":0}}}
```

Update the event as "numbered":

```
{"recurrence":{"pattern":{"type":"daily","interval":1,"month":0,"dayOfMonth":0,"firstDayOfWeek":"sunday","index":"first"},"range":{"type":"numbered","startDate":"2020-10-06","endDate":"0001-01-01","recurrenceTimeZone":"Central Standard Time","numberOfOccurrences":5}}}
```

The following video displays the behavior the google attendee is experiencing:
https://www.screencast.com/t/uhwovvZf

Note: At the end of the video I show that switching the interval to 2 will cause the google event to be updated properly, so this is specifically a problem when the interval is 1.

Is this a known bug? Does anyone have a work-around for it?

Comment: can you repro the issue consistently? Also outside of the code, have you tried with MS Graph Explorer or POSTMAN and notice that you can repro the issue or not?

Comment: Yes, I have reproduced the behavior consistently. Yes, I have used the graph explorer to reproduce the behavior- the calls are in the post. Thanks!